# Get post values of form created by widget in sidebar

Tags: plugins, widgets

I have created this widget function to show a subscription form but from here i am not able to get the the values of input fields when someone submit it. Please help to get post values of the form.

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract( $args );
    // these are the widget options
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    echo $before_widget;
    echo '<div>';

    // Check if title is set
    if ( $title ) {
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
    }
    ?>
    <form>
        <p><label for="db_sub_name">Name</label> <input type="text" name="db_sub_name" id="db_sub_name" value="" placeholder="Enter your Name"></p>
        <p><label for="db_sub_name">Email</label> <input type="text" name="db_sub_email" id="db_sub_email" value="" placeholder="Enter your Email"></p>
        <p ><input style="float:right;" type="submit" /></p>
    </form>

    <?php


    echo '</div>';
    echo $after_widget;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you collecting the name & email? Are you just having it delivered to your email?

Comment: i just want to get post value inside plugin i know how to add them in database or email them

Answer (score 1):

Your form needs to have `method="post"` and `action="someScript.php"` defined. It will send the post variables to wherever you deifine in your `action=""`

```
<form method="post" action="someScript.php" >
   <p>
     <label for="db_sub_name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="db_sub_name" id="db_sub_name" value="" placeholder="Enter your     Name">
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="db_sub_name">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="db_sub_email" id="db_sub_email" value="" placeholder="Enter your Email">
   </p>
   <p>
     <input style="float:right;" type="submit" />
   </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a plugin for that? There is a nice mailchimp plugin available with a widget and submission form, [Mailchimp For WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/).

It populates your mailchimp account and that is an awesome tool for marketing emails...